# At what point does the system check for the Android Manifest?

Tags: android

Does the **Android Manifest** check for the available components to be used before an application starts running, or does the system check for the **Android Manifest** every time a new component is being instantiated? By components I mean *activities, services,* etc...
What is the process involved?

Also, can an application still go back and forth to check on the android manifest even after it is running to check on xml activity attributes such as the *android:name, android:label*, or even intent filters, for different purposes such as to see whether a component to be used has already been defined?

Comment: Since the manifest file contains the very first settings an app will check, I'd say: `as soon as the app starts`.

Answer (score 2):

Well to say it in a simple way-

Manifest contains permission like- "SD card read/write permission". So, while installing an app if you don't have a SD card than your won't get installed.

Again manifest contains "minimum SDK version"- which checks what OS version you have in your mobile, if your mobile OS version is less than the minimum version defined in manifest than the app won't install in your mobile.

In the manifest you have a list of all the activities and services too. So, without adding these in the manifest- your activities/services wont work.

So, these sort of checking and permissions are in manifest - the information the system must have before it can run any of the app's code.

Hope i have been able to keep it short and simple  :-D

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Do you know if a running app has constant access to the android manifest though? For example, if it is creating a new component instance and it has to check for attributes like android:name on the manifest to see if it is allowed, or to get the label from the android:name, etc..Though you have made a great contribution, you have not specified how or when it really does it. I know this is a low level question but I would like to know.

Comment: I am afraid that i did not understand your question. But as far as i understood - you are talking about initializing components like button, textview etc. For using any view in layout xml file - you need to set an ID & eg- <TextView id="@+id/text"> . And you initialize the view by its id. FOr more plz read: http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=2883&ownerUserId=satya

Answer (score 2):

The manifest is a part of the app - it gets packaged with the app in its installation APK.

The manifest *tells* the system what APIs the application will use. When the app is installed, the system tells the user what sets of potentially sensitive APIs the application will use (as listed int he manifest) and if the user allows the app to be installed the system then assumes that the use of those APIs is permitted.

The OS will not permit the app to use other sensitive APIs that the app did not declare in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Android Manifest file contains important information like the Java package name of the application, permissions, descriptions about activities,services... The system must have these information before running the app code.By this reason, the system doesn´t check the Android Manifest in runtime.

More here:
[Android Manifest - Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)